# C# - webClient.DownloadDataAsync Throwing an Ecxception in webbrowser control

Tags: c#, https, ssl-certificate, webclient

I am trying to download a json string from server by using below lines of code

```
private void webBrowser1_Navigating(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
    WebClient client = new WebClient();

    client.DownloadDataCompleted += new DownloadDataCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadDataCompleted);

    client.DownloadDataAsync(new Uri("https://myApp:8070/api/account"));
}

void client_DownloadDataCompleted(object sender, DownloadDataCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    string filepath = textBox1.Text;
    File.WriteAllBytes(filepath, e.Result);
    MessageBox.Show("File downloaded");
}
```

But getting an exception like below

```
System.Net.WebException: 'The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.'
```

Getting same exception for **DownloadStringAsync** also, but **DownloadFileAsync** is working fine.

Did I miss any thing?

Comment: If you do this in a browser do you get any SSL certificate errors?

Comment: I agree with @Equalsk https://success.outsystems.com/Support/Enterprise_Customers/Troubleshooting/%22Could_not_establish_trust_relationship_for_the_SSL%2F%2FTLS%22_error

Comment: Yes you are right, I am not getting any error in browser(Chrome). Missing of certificates is may be the reason to get this error

Comment: But how can I escape this, I need to do this via webbrowser, because I need to provide SSO sign in feature for user